# Determining constructibility of roots of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Determine whether the roots of the following polynomials are constructible:

(1) $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

(2) $x^3+x^2+x+1$

My understanding is that if the polynomial in question is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the extension degree is equal to the degree of the polynomial. Therefore, as the extension degree must be a power of $2$, we can for instance argue that in (2) if the polynomial is irreducible the roots cannot be constructible since $3$ is not a power of $2$. This line of proof would be hard for (1) seeing as the polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein and has degree a power of $2$. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Presumably you are speaking of the splitting field, not just the field obtained by adjoining a single root.  In which case all you know is that the degree of the extension is $≤n!$, where $n$ is the polynomial degree.

Comment: And note:  $-1$ is a root of the second polynomial.

Comment: @lulu in that case how can we determine which of the roots, if any, are constructible by ruler and compass?

Comment: you can factor the 2nd polynomial into $$(x+1)(x^2+1)$$ and notice that -1 is definitely constructible while the polynomial in (1) and $x^2+1$ are cyclotomic polynomials, whose roots are just the primitive roots of unity. Then it's easy to check whether or not the roots are constructible

Comment: The definitive result for constructible numbers is as follows: let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C} $ be algebraic and let $f(x) \in\mathbb{Q} [x] $ be its minimal polynomial. Further let $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x) $. Then $\alpha$ is constructible if and only $[L:\mathbb{Q}] $ is a power of $2$.